# More than one mmdrv running

Tags: performance-testing, loadrunner

I am using loadrunner Controller 11 and load generator having a capacity of 400 users.

While executing scripts in the controller, I see that for each script the respective mmdrv is running in the task manager, i.e. if 10 scripts are executing, there are 10 mmdrv running.

In run-time settings we select the "Run Vuser as thread" option.

Because of more mmdrv instances, the memory occupation and CPU utilization are high.

Because of this constant increase, I am not able to push more than 200 users. How can I overcome this?

Protocol: Web http/html protocol.

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: More mmdrv running and LG capacity is 400 users.now currently I am able to scaleup to 200 users.

Comment: do you see 200 mmdrv processes when you run load of 200 users? what is the protocol you are using for scripts?

Answer (score 0):

Please check your script if there are any custom codes written if yes, try to reduce the custom code as much as possible. If you are allocating memory dynamically try to free at the end of each iteration.